# Extracting field ......TypeError: String indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

file `test1.log`:

```
{'Python' : '.py', 'C++' : '.cpp', 'length' : 24}
```

```
def validate_file(f):
    #print('File Header Validation:')

    fname=open(f)
    count=0
    for line in fname:
        if 'length' in line:
            print(line['length'])


validate_file("test1.log")
```

I am trying to find the value of `length`?here's the output after reading text from file `test1.log` :

```
print(line['length'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any help how can I extract the value of 'length' field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to do that like:

#### Code:

```
def validate_file(f):
    with open(f) as contents:
        for line in contents:
            data = ast.literal_eval(line)
            if 'length' in data:
                print(data['length'])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import ast
validate_file("test1.log")
```

#### Results:

```
24
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to JSON first.

```
line = json.loads(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You accessing the wrong way, the line which you have is in dict format so load the lone in json and use the get method for accessing the key

*test1.log* value in double quotes

```
{"Python" : ".py", "C++" : ".cpp", "length" : 24}


def validate_file(f):
    #print('File Header Validation:')
    fname=open(f)
    count=0
    for line in fname:
        line=json.loads(line)
        print(line.get("length",""))#if length not then nothing print
```

Comment: tried it and getting this error message:    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: data required in double quotes : {"Python" : ".py", "C++" : ".cpp", "length" : 24}